# What type of fork is Litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, blockchain-fork, soft-fork

Is Litecoin classified as either a hard fork or soft fork? If neither, what is considered as?

Comment: It's an altcoin. A fork implies that a _split_ occurs, they thus have a shared transaction _history_. Litecoin, afaik, started with a completely new genenesis block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's considered a source code fork, or an altcoin, neither a hard fork nor soft fork of bitcoin. To be classified as a soft/hard fork, it should share some of the same chain from the genesis block. LN has a completely different chain right from the start so it's not a fork of the bitcoin chain.

Note that even coins sharing the same chain as bitcoin from the genesis block, e.g. BCH, are not considered hard forks by most people because they are not "bitcoin". They are generally termed "forkcoins"

Comment: Appreciate the explanation--just to check on the last point--does that essentially mean 'forkcoin' potentially synonymous with something being a soft or hard fork depending on who you ask?

Comment: @jlw yes I'm sure some hardcore BCH supporters would call it a hardfork rather than an altcoin, but to most people it's clear it's an altcoin

Answer (score 0):

Litecoin is neither a hard or a soft fork. The codebase is a fork from Bitcoin codebase but it by no means share any history with the Bitcoin blockchain and thus considered as a separate alternative cryptocurrency to Bitcoin.

It is now trading at $179 https://www.coingecko.com/en/price_charts/litecoin/usd